# Rasa Slack Integration Issue

Tags: slack, slack-api, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-x

I am using rasa to connect to slack using Ngrok.

My bot is properly responding with RASA X. These are steps i have done to connect with slack.

1. Create new Channel.
2. Added new user in App home(new in slack, worked with dialogflow for me).
3. Added the URL in event subscription like this:

   Event Subscription containing ngrok/webhook url

   [image]
4. subscribed to following bot events.

   [image]
5. Added localhost to redirect URL

   [image]
6. Installed the app to a channel
   Copied the Bot User OAuth Access Token to my credentials file:

   [image]
7. then started the bot using rasa run on port 5005 where ngrok is running
   I get the response from slack into rasa (rasa run actions terminal, trying to run some google drive api).
   Even simple bot is not responding to a hi msg tried that also.

   Only in cmd i get the response, which means that msg is coming from slack to the rasa

   [image]

And no message is fetched back in rasa window.

Note : i have also used

```
rasa run -m models --enable-api --cors “*” --debug
```

to debug the output and it shows clearly message coming to rasa from slack, bot predicting correct intent and uttering correct response. but this msg is not getting fetched back to slack

Comment: Besides subscribing to bot events, did you also add corresponding `oauth scopes` ? Can you DM the bot and get a response in Slack?

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. I have solved the issue and have posted an step by step guide on rasa forum. https://forum.rasa.com/t/rasa-slack-bot-integration/25973

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I'll post the link as an answer; feel free to post it yourself and accept as answer if you'd rather